About the sets in python
import string

alphabet = set(string.ascii_lowercase)

def is_pangram_alternative(s):
    return not (set(alphabet) - set(s))

input_string = 'The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog'
if is_pangram_alternative(input_string):
    print("Yes")
else:
    print("No")

in the above code when this happens set(alphabet) - set(s) it eliminates all the lowercase alphabets and there will be only uppercase and whitespaces remaining as per the difference between the sets it should return false but how does it produces the results correctly

set(alphabet) - set(s) will not leave "only uppercase and whitespaces remaining" . That would be set(s) - set(alphabet).

In the provided function (is_pangram_alternative) alphabet is already of type set and you don't need the set(alphabet)

The math terminology here is that set subtraction is not "Commutative". i.e. A - B != B - A for all sets A and B.

What is the purpose of is_pangram_alternative()? It isn't designed to test if a string is a pangram, so I am wondering what is the intention. You want it to return  uppercase and whitespaces in the input string, and how would the absence of a letter in the input string affect the return value?

set(alphabet) - set(s)

tells us anything in the alphabet that isn't in s. We get an empty set.
If we try
set(s) - set(alphabet)

we get {'T', ' '}
So, try you subset the other way round, and maybe lowercase the letters?

Assume that input_string is a pangram, and a case-sensitive one at that , i.e., containing all lower case letters (if you want a case-insensitive pangram checker, you should convert yourinput_string to al lower case with .lower() before proceeding). In this case, set(s) will return a set of all 26 lower case letters, which is identical to set(alphabet), so set(alphabet) - set(s) will get you an empty set, which not then turns into True. But if input_string is not a pangram, there will be letters remaining in set(alphabet) after the subtraction, so you get a non-empty set, which not turns into False.
Note that the presence of an upper-case T in input_string does not alter this, because you're subtracting set(s) from set(alphabet) rather than the other way around.

Technically lowercasing the input string gives you a cased string, not a caseless string, so isn't a valid operation for case insensitive comparison. Ok, I know that you can get away with such imprecisions with English only content. But that doesn't make it case-insensitive.

Existing issues with the answer as indicated in existing answer and comments:

Order of set differences is significant
Casing is significant
alphabet is already a set, so you don't want to take a set of a set

If you disregard case, then The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog is a pangram, but if you take case into account, it isn't a pangram. In theory your code should return No.
Also your code does not take whitespace, punctuation, and non-print characters into account.
I'd also note the following code isn't a universal test for pangrams, only for English pangrams. Very extensive re-coding would be needed to create a generic pangram detector.
I'd lower case the string, and use the regex module to remove characters we don't want in the set comparison, then test if the sets are equal.
To be a pangram, the two sets should be equal, if the string contains additional letters outside of a to z, then it isn't a pangram. Likewise it doesn't contain all the letters a to z, it also isn't a pangram.
import regex
import string

alphabet = set(string.ascii_lowercase)

input_string = 'The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog'

def is_pangram_alternative(s):
    s = regex.sub(r'[\p{P}\p{Z}\p{N}]+', '', s.lower())
    print('Yes') if set(s) == alphabet else print('No')

is_pangram_alternative(input_string)


thank you for clarifying the doubt. ' what does the empty string do  , ' ',  do in the regex function that you have used

@purplcow each match is replaced by an empty string. So in this case any punctuation, whitespace and separators, numbers and control characters are replaced by an empty string, i.e. removed from the string.
